# Using photocopy of visa for US border from old passport

Tags: paperwork, b1-b2-visas

Good afternoon All,

I am traveling to the US from the UK, only passing through to Canada.  I have a Valid B2 Tourist visa. However, it's in my old passport, which is in my home country.  I have my new passport with me.  Would the US border accept a picture of my Visa that is in my old passport if I got a family member to take a photo including the informational page of the passport containing my info?

---

Thank's all, Based on this and my own thinking I have just booked a new flight direct,

Comment: No. You need the original passport. Family member could send you (e.g. overnight package). Not cheap

Comment: Unlikely.  The Visa is what the US CBP scan (rather than your valid/current passport) when you enter, so on that alone I'd think it very unlikely they'd accept a copy of the visa.  Add to that various other reasons it becomes even less likely.

Comment: Thank's all,  Based on this and my own thinking I have just booked a new flight direct,

Comment: Yes, there's no other way. If you need a visa to enter the US and you don't have it with you, you won't even be allowed to board a US-bound flight. However, if your intended destination is Canada, it is anyway a better idea to fly from the UK directly to Canada, even if you did have a US visa. Why would anyone want to go through two immigration controls instead of just one? If there were no direct flights to Canada from your current country of residence (which is not the case in the UK), you could also apply for a US transit visa. But that's not necessary in your case.

Comment: @Midavalo CBP scans both the visa and the passport.  They will certainly require the original visa to be presented in any case.

Comment: @phoog I have presented both to CBP many times, and I don't recall a single time that they've scanned the passport.  Both when my visa was in my current passport, and when I had two (one current, one expired).  But as you say the original visa will be required either way.

Comment: @phoog to clarify - they always want to _see_ both passports, but they (in my experience) seem to only scan the visa.  Maybe it's a land border thing?

Comment: @Midavalo biometric passports may be scanned through the embedded chip, not necessarily through a photo-scanner. Visa has to be scanned by the photo-scanner.

Comment: @littleadv in order to read the passport chip it is necessary to present a key comprising the bearer's date of birth and the passport's number and expiration date, which are normally acquired by the optical scanner. The passport number and date of birth are shown on a US nonimmigrant visa, but not the expiration date. This could of course be retrieved with a database lookup, but if this is in fact how it works then it would be necessary to scan a new passport on its first use after the old passport's expiration to record its number and expiration date and to link the document to the visa.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule the US only accept the original visa in the passport and it is very likely you will not get a chance to  ask a border official as airlines tend to stop you from boarding if you do not have the right paperwork as they explain the rules.

The easiest solution is a direct flight, the second best option is to get someone to send the passport to you with a fast and secure method.